# Left align first line of equation (and other complex align)

Tags: equations, align

```
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, amsthm}
\begin{align}\label{eq1}
\sum_{n}\lambda^{n}(i)-\sum_{n}\lambda^{n}(j) \nonumber\\=\begin{cases}
    \lambda_{n},  &\text{if } n = i\\
    -\lambda_{n}, &\text{if } n = i\\
    0, &\text{otherwise}
    \end{cases} 
    \text{ }\forall i, j
\end{align}
```

First line of the equation must be left aligned (or at least adjustable,  `\hspace` not working). `\sum_{n}\lambda^{n}(i)-\sum_{n}\lambda^{n}(j) \nonumber` then according to first line `cases` will be aligned. However, equation number should be at extreme right.

As per clarification request by @Mico The first pic from the answer.

[image]
What I need is the following pic:

[image]

The alignment of the starting of the equation is preferably left (or adjustable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what the proposed alignment should achieve, but here it is:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item sample equation
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
\hspace{\dimexpr\displaywidth-\linewidth}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\sum_{n}\lambda^{n}(i)
&-\sum_{n}\lambda^{n}(j)\\
&=\begin{cases}
  \lambda_{n},  & \text{if $n = i$}\\
  -\lambda_{n}, & \text{if $n = i$}\\
  0,            & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases} 
  \quad\forall\, i, j
\end{aligned}
\hspace{10000pt minus 1fil}
\end{equation}

\item sample equation
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
\begin{split}
\sum_{n}\lambda^{n}(i)
&-\sum_{n}\lambda^{n}(j)\\
&=\begin{cases}
  \lambda_{n},  & \text{if $n = i$}\\
  -\lambda_{n}, & \text{if $n = i$}\\
  0,            & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases} 
  \quad\forall\, i, j
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `fleqn` environment, from `nccmath`. The distance from the left margin can be set as an optional argument. Incidentally, I replaced the `cases` environment with `cases*` for simpler typing of the text part:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox} 
\newcommand\eqmathbox[2][]{\eqmakebox[#1][r]{$ #2 $}}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Sample equation: 
\begin{fleqn}
  \begin{align}\label{eq1}
    \sum_{n}\lambda^{n}(i)
                       & -\sum_{n}\lambda^{n}(j) \nonumber \\
                       & = \begin{cases*}
    \eqmathbox[C]{\lambda_{n}}, & if $n = i$ \\
    \eqmathbox[C]{-\lambda_{n}}, & if $n = i$ \\
    \eqmathbox[C]{0}, & otherwise
    \end{cases*}
    \qquad \forall i, j
  \end{align}
\end{fleqn}


\item Sample equation \texttt{(with optional argument)}: 
\begin{fleqn}[2em]
  \begin{align}\label{eq2}
    \sum_{n}\lambda^{n}(i)
                       & -\sum_{n}\lambda^{n}(j) \nonumber \\
                       & =\begin{cases*}
    \eqmathbox[C]{\lambda_{n}}, & if $n = i$ \\
    \eqmathbox[C]{-\lambda_{n}}, & if $n = i$ \\
    \eqmathbox[C]{0}, & otherwise
    \end{cases*}
    \qquad \forall i, j
  \end{align}
\end{fleqn}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: My editor, and above all my absent-mindedness, struck again! I've fixed it. Thank you for patiently pointing these problems. B.t.w., in your code (which I shamelessly stole to have a basis),  `\hfill` doesn't work. I circumvented it using `eqmakebox`.

Comment: FWIW, `\hfill` does work with `cases` environments. :-) It's just the `cases*` environment where it doesn't work...

Comment: Is it a bug in  ` cases*`? This means I simplified the typing of the text part by complexifying the math part. Communicating vessels…

Comment: I definitely would not claim that it's a bug in `cases`. The `cases*` environment of the `mathtools` package is of much more recent vintage than the `cases` environment is. The author and maintainer of the `mathtools` package presumably had their reasons for programming up the `cases*` environment they way they did. But it does mean that there's more than just one difference (viz., math mode or text mode for the second column) between `cases` and `cases*`.

Comment: Do note, by the way, that I used `\hfill` in my (now deleted) answer because I was addressing the original form of the query. The OP subsequently changed his/her query massively, to the point where the original material basically disappeared entirely. One of the (many) changes the OP brought about was that the first column of the `cases` (or `cases*`) environment is no longer required to be right-aligned. Sigh.